# Pass user id when creating an association between two other models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I'm totally stuck on something that seems like it should be so simple.  I have a subscription model that creates an association with an account model.  This part works fine by using:

```
after_create :create_account
```

What i want is to pass the user into the account record, ideally as the account_manager.  I have a user_id field as well but I prefer to use the account_manager_id.  I can do this fine manually but to have it happen automatically is tripping me up.  I've tried a variety of methods to pass the current user into the account by putting a variety of options in my account controller under create.  So far no luck.  Does anyone have any ideas?

```
@account = Account.new(params[:account].merge(account_manager_id: current_owner))


@user = current_user
@account = @user.accounts.create(params[:account])


@account = Account.new(account_params)
@account.account_manager = current_user


@account = current_user.accounts.build(params[:account])
```

My account controller

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController

  def index
     @accounts = Account.all
  end

  def show
    @account = Account.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
   @account = Account.new
  end

  def edit
    @account = Account.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create 
    @account = Account.new(account_params)
    @account.account_manager = current_user
      if @account.save
        flash[:success] = "Content Successfully Created"
        redirect_to @account
      else
        render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
     @account = Account.find(params[:id])
      if @account.update(account_params)
        flash[:success] = "Your account was successfully updated"
        redirect_to current_user
      else
         render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
  @account = Account.find(params[:id])
    @account.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      flash[:info] = "The grant was successfully destroyed"
    end
  end

  private

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def account_params
      params.require(:account).permit(:name, :user_id, :account_manager_id,:subscription_id)
    end
end
```

account.rb

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  belongs_to :account_manager, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'account_manager_id'
  belongs_to :subscription, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :subscription
    has_and_belongs_to_many :account
```

subscription.rb

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Koudoku::Subscription

  has_one :account
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :coupon
  after_create :create_account #after a subscription is created, automatically create an associtaed account

end
```

Comment: Provide the code for the models and the controller for review.

Comment: Are you getting errors? If so, please post. Also, you spell "manager" wrong ("manger") in several places.

Comment: ah, good catch on the "manager".  I'm not getting any errors on the site when i create a subscription.  But when I check Account.all account_manager_id and user_id are both nil.

Comment: So I doubled checked my "manager" spelling and still am not passing the current user.  I do see  Subscription Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "subscriptions".* FROM "subscriptions" WHERE "subscriptions"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 18]] in the logs.  Maybe I can use the  user_id from the subscription because it is the same person.

Comment: So what exactly is the issue? Is the AccountsController#create is failing? If so, please provide the stacktrace or the error message that is being thrown.

Comment: I'm not getting any error message.  The account is being created when i create a subscription but the problem is the current user is not being added to the account record under account_manager_id.  When i check Account.all I see the account but account_manager_id is nil.   My question is how to pass the current user id as account_manager when i create the account.  I'm not sure what a stacktrace is but I'd be happy to look if you let me know how.

Comment: @Dharam I'm still not being able to pass the current user as the account manager when creating a new account.  Any advice?

Comment: @railsie: I am a bit confused here. Are you expecting the `account` that gets created as part of the callback when a `subscription` is created to have the `account_manager` be filled with the `current_user`? Or are you expecting the `account` that gets created from `AccountsController` to have the `account_manager` be filled with the `current_user`?

Comment: What I originally thought is that I could use 'after_create :create_account' with the AccountsController to have the account_manager be filled in with the current_user.  After testing it seems the AccountsController isn't even used when I use after_create :create_account.   So now I'm trying to def create_account but I can't seem to get the current user at all.  The best I have done so far is 'Account.create :account_manager_id => "1"'.  Problem is that only works for the first user.  How would I define the current user there?

Answer (score 0):

Took out

```
after_create :create_account
```

and added the following

```
# subscriptions_controller.rb
def create
  ...
  if @subscription.save
    @subscription.create_account(account_manager: current_user)
  end
end
```